# Scaling fractions

Tags: functions, fractions

I have a set of values between $0$ and $1$ inclusive and I want to scale them so that they are all between $0.5$ and $1$ inclusive. What function can I use to do this?

\begin{align}
    f(0) &\to 0.5\\
    f(0.5) &\to 0.75\\
    f(1) &\to 1
\end{align}

Comment: Depends if you can add a shift. You can't scale 0 to anything, you need to add a shift

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want this scale to be linear, use
$$
f(x) = 0.5 + 0.5x = \frac{1+x}{2}
$$